# stop while loop after downloading email attachments - python

Tags: python, do-while

I have got the below python code to download attachments from outlook Inbox, Subfolder COC. The code is working fine but does not stop once all the attachments have been downloaded. How can I fix it please.

```
import win32com.client

import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("COC") # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference

messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()

 

while True:

 

    try:

        print (message)

        attachments = message.Attachments

        attachment = attachments.Item(1)

        attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment)) #Saves to the attachment to current folder

        print (attachment)

        message = messages.GetNext()

 

    except:

        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Comment: It might be easier to rearrange your code for downloading attachments around `for attachment in message.Attachments:` rather than an `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a while loop use a for loop

```
for message in messages:
    try:
        attachments = message.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment)) #Saves to the attachment to current folder
        print(attachment)
        print(message)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a `try`/`except` which just ignores all errors; you should only ignore specific errors which you know are OK

Comment: Echoing @sabik that is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

So long the condition remains true, the while loop will continue to run forever. Just increment the loop to ensure it becomes false at the end.
For example you could set a variable status above the while loop and set it to true.....
The condition of the while loop can then be while status == true.
At the end of the loop redeclare status to be == false

Answer (score 0):

When the `message.GetNext()` method indicates that there are no more messages, you can either change the condition to use that instead of `True`, or (if necessary) use the `break` statement to exit the loop.

As a side note, it's not a good idea to have a `try`/`except` which just ignores all errors; you should only ignore specific errors which you know are OK.

---

The precise code depends on how `message.GetNext()` indicates there are no more messages, which you can either look up in the docs, or try it and see; however, assuming it returns `None`, the code would look like this:

```
message = messages.GetFirst()

while message is not None:
    print (message)
    # process the message, download the attachments etc

    message = messages.GetNext()
```